# Calculational of conditional expectations

Tags: self-study, conditional-expectation

Let $X$ and $Y$ be iid random variables, with $P(X=k)=2^-k$ for $k=1,2,3.....$. Find $P(X>Y)$ and $P(X>2Y)$.

I solved this question by applying transformations and got $P(X>Y)=2/3$ and $P(X>2Y)=1/(4(2^0.5-1)$.
My intuition tells me that $P(X>Y)$ should have come out to be $1/2$ since $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables.

Now, There was this other question in which $X$ and $Y$ are iid exponential random variables with mean $p>0$. Define Z by:
$Z=1 if X<Y$ and $Z=0 otherwise$. Find the conditional mean $E(X|Z=1)$.
As per my intuition, $P(Y>X)=1/2$ then, why didn't the results align with the intuition in the previous question?

Is there is a difference in the basic understanding of the two scenarios.
Also, I couldn't proceed further to calculate the conditional mean. Please help.

Comment: $P(X>Y)$ would have been $1/2$ by symmetry but there is positive probability of the event $\{X=Y\}$ as the distribution is discrete.

Comment: Okay, so precisely this is the reason why $P(X>Y)$ comes out to be zero in the continuous distribution case and not in the discrete distribution case.

Comment: Could you also help me to calculate the conditional expectation?

Comment: $P(X=Y)=0$  when $(X,Y)$ is continuous.The conditional expectation is a separate question and it is not clear to me what is your work on that. Anyway I had asked this sometime back: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2674927/321264.

Comment: @StubbornAtom thankyou

Comment: P(X<Y∣X)=1−FY(X)=e−X/λ I cannot figure out how this statement in the question in the link is reasonable, given that X and Y are independent.

Answer (score 1):

The differences between the discrete and continuous cases have been well explained in the comments.  For the conditional expectation in the exponential case with density $f_X(x)=e^{-x/p}/p$ for $x>0$, I suggest first working out the conditional density as $$f_{X|Z=1}(x) = f_{X|X<Y}(x) = \frac{2}{p}e^{-2x/p},\quad x>0.$$ This utilizes $P(X<Y)=1/2$, as mentioned. Then the conditional expectation is a simple integral: $$\int_0^\infty xf_{X|X<Y}(x) dx = \frac{p}{2}.$$ Alternatively, you can just note that $f_{X|X<Y}(x)$ is the exponential distribution with mean $p/2$, hence that is the mean.

Further details on the conditional density: The joint density is $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = e^{-x/p}e^{-y/p}/p^2$, for $x,y>0$.  Then, for $w>0$,
$$P(X> w|X<Y) = 2P(w<X<Y)=2\int_w^\infty \int_x^\infty f_{X,Y}(x,y) dydx.$$ After a little calculus this equals $e^{-2w/p}$. Then $$f_{X|X<Y}(w)=\frac{d}{dw}P(X\le w|X<Y)=\frac{d}{dw}(1-e^{-2w/p}),$$ which gives the formula above.

Comment: How did you calculate the conditional density?

Comment: Added some details on the conditional density.

Comment: $P(Y>X|X)=1-P(Y>X)$ this thing specifically is where I'm not comfortable  @Dedekind Cuts if you explain this

Comment: You can recall that $P(A|B) = 1-P(A^c|B)$

Comment: Did you mean $P(Y>X|X)=1-P(Y<X|X)$?